# Applepay calculated twice on total amount report - Wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, applepay

Wordpress woocommerce on the report is calculating the applepay twice.
For example Paypal + Stripe + CC + Applepay + Applepay

I am not sure where to look for the querie where is calculating these things. 
Its not in the dashboard, it has to be somewhere in the woocommerce code where there is some bug or conflict in the code that is calculating the applepay twice. I need the querie that is calculating...

Comment: Have you looked for the query?

Comment: Yes, have searched whole woocommerce and couldnt find it. If anyone has idea where it is, i would be gratefull...